# Need help converting the string stored in "role" to uppercase letters using the .toUppecase() method

Tags: javascript, toupper

```js
let firstName = "Sean";
let lastName = "Bowden";
let role = 'developer';
var msg = firstName + " " + lastName + ": " + role + ".";
```

I need to convert the role variable to all upper case letters using the .toUpperCase() method.

Output will be: `Sean Bowden: DEVELOPER.`

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out.

```
let firstName = "Sean"; 
let lastName = "Bowden"; 
let role = 'developer'; 
role = role.toUpperCase()

var msg = firstName + " " + lastName + ": " + role + ".";
```

or

```
    let firstName = "Sean"; 
    let lastName = "Bowden"; 
    let role = 'developer'; 

    var msg = firstName + " " + lastName + ": " + role.toUpperCase() + ".";
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, try using:

`var msg =fisrstname + " " + lastname + ": " + role.toUpperCase() + ".";`

Note: The `toUpperCase()` method does not change the original string.

Tip: Use the `toLowerCase()` method to convert a string to lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let firstName = "Sean";
let lastName = "Bowden";
let role = "developer".toUpperCase();
var msg = firstName + " " + lastName + ": " + role + ".";

console.log(msg);
```